# What is the difference between TF 2.0 Alpha and TF nightly preview?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Is there any difference between them, in terms of stability, which one is more recent etc.
Additionally, what should I expect in the coming months, a beta version? and then final release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.0 alpha is the Tensorflow 2.0 alpha version released on the Tensorflow dev summit 2019 day. Its API is "stable" (that means, it doesn't change every day), although it is explicitly an alpha version, hence something can't work as you expect.

The nightly builds, instead, are builds created daily with the changes occurring on the master branch of the Tensorflow repo. The API changes often (e.g. 2 days ago the symbol `tf.mod` was a thing, now it is present only in `tf.math.mod`) and is more "unstable" then the alpha itself.

In the coming months... who knows. The first release candidate was planned for "spring" 2019 - but spring is a flexible concept (quote from Martin Wicke - "Spring is a sort of flexible concept").

Comment: It is not only a flexible concept, but also regionalist. Why do you assume that all people are living in the same hemisphere as you? I'm confused when you say Spring, it is Autumn here in OZ.